# Getting the string inside of a the first paragraph in a blogpost

Tags: php

Imagine my string is

```
$str = "<p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p><p>paragraph 3</p>";
```

and I want to get...

```
$firstParagraph = "paragraph 1"
```

What would be the best way of doing that?

Is it possible to split each paragraph into an array easily?

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm to angry today, sorry, but it looks like you looking for somebody who will just write code for you, because you don't want to think about it. Tell us, at least, which functions and algorithms you have tried already.

Comment: You definitely _are_ too angry. Do it like me and drink a beer.

Comment: @Leif I can't believe that people are so lazy. But I'll follow your advice about beer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$res = $xp->query('//p');

$firstParagraph = $res[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: you can't access the DOMNodeList items with array-style syntax... you should instead use [`->item(0)`](http://php.net/domnodelist.item).  Why go with XPath anyway when `getElementsByTagName()` does the job just fine?

Comment: Probably because that's just a simplified snippet of a larger document, for which xpath would be more appropriate.

Comment: What gives you that impression? The questions asks for the first/each paragraph.

Comment: @salathe: "Imagine my string is" - but that is irrelevant really.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two things. But with

```
$array = preg_split('#</p><p>|<p>|</p>#i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

you can split the paragraphs into an array, $string being your string with the paragraphs.

To get the first paragraph only, use:

```
preg_match('#^<p>(.*?)</p>#i', $string, $matches)
```

$matches will contain what you want. And this is even more memory efficient and quicker than the previous regex. I shouldn't have to mention that solutions with object oriented xml parsers are total overkills if I've ever seen one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm typing this up quickly, but wouldn't:

```
$str = "<p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p><p>paragraph 3</p>";
preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i', $str, $paragraphs);
echo $paragraphs[0]; // Paragraph 1
```

work more efficiently than these other solutions?